# Distributed Unsupervised Learning in SageMaker

Tags: unsupervised-learning, distributed-training, amazon-machine-learning, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

I am running local unsupervised learning (predominantly clustering) on a large, single node with GPU.

Does SageMaker support **distributed unsupervised learning** using **clustering**?

If yes, please provide the relevant example (preferably non-TensorFlow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SageMaker Training allow you to bring your own training scripts, and supports various forms of distributed training, like data/model parallel, and frameworks like PyTorch DDP, Horovod, DeepSpeed, etc.
Additionally, if you want to bring your data, but not code, [SageMaker training offers various unsupervised built-in algorithms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/algorithms-unsupervised.html), some of which are parallelizable.